# Prevent Jcarousel from resetting to beginning position on page postback?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, query-string, jcarousel

I have a nice looking jarousel running from an asp:listview element, with asp:imagebuttons for the images. When clicked, the images in the carousel send the image id to querystring, and the new page is loaded with a larger version of the image and some asp:labels are filled in to describe the image. It looks and works great, except once the page reloads the jcarousel resets to original position, which is confusing to the user.

What's the best way to prevent this? I tried using an UpdatePanel but couldn't figure out how to pass the querystring variable with the partial page update. I could pass the variable in a hidden field, but this wouldn't be very SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Set autoeventwireup=false on your aspx page and handle all the events yourself... that way, then something is clicked, the page doesn't run through the page event life cycle and reset everything

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? I'm not sure how I can adjust the page cycle for a jquery object like jcarousel..